# C++ error: expression list treated as compound expression in mem-initializer [-fpermissive]|

Tags: c++, class

I was trying to implement the K-means algorithm in C++, by following this short tutorial: https://reasonabledeviations.com/2019/10/02/k-means-in-cpp/

When trying to build the first part of the project, the compiler gives me the following error:

```
C:\Users\COMPUTER\Desktop\Python\K-means algorithm\main.cpp|22|error: expression list treated as compound expression in mem-initializer [-fpermissive]|
```

The error seems to lie  in how I assign the minimum distance in line 22,
thus `minDist(__DBL_MAX__){}`

I have tried assigning an `int` to the assigned number `__DBL_MAX__`, as other answers might have suggested, but when I did, other bugs appeared.
What can I do to solve this?
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// Inizializzare il punto
struct Point {
  double x, y;    // Coordinate del punto
  int cluster;    // Cluster di default
  double minDist; // Distanza minima
  int z;

  Point() : x(0, 0), y(0, 0), cluster(-1), minDist(__DBL_MAX__) {}

  Point(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y), cluster(-1), minDist(__DBL_MAX__) {}

  double distance(Point p) {
    return (p.x - x) * (p.x - x) + (p.y - y) * (p.y - y);
  }
};
```

Comment: there is a typo in this line `x(0,0), y(0,0),` , change it to `x(0.0), y(0.0)`

Answer (score 2):

in the constructor Point():

you can't initialize double like that x(0,0), y(0,0)
replace that by x(0.0), y(0.0)

Comment: I noticed it now, thanks really much! It's just that I was checking on the code below, and didn't think at all about how x is declared, anyway it works now. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, it happens ... keep going